# Question about managing the Preferences window (Python)

Tags: python, interface

```
  def open_user_pref():
      addon_prefs = get_addon_preferences()# function return my addon pref
      bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT') # open preferences window
      addon_prefs.active_section = 'ADDONS' # go to addon sections
      bpy.ops.preferences.addon_expand(module=get_addon_name())# get_addon_name() it is a small function that returns the name of the addon (For my convenience)
      bpy.ops.preferences.addon_show(module=get_addon_name()) # Show my addon pref
```

This is a small function that I would like to improve, so it opens the preferences window on my addon, but I would like to enter other things:

For example:

- Check if the window is open in front of the screen (Not minimized) to
  avoid reopening steps which would be useless
- Resize the window (If possible)
- Check if the window is minimized and if it is, reopen it in front of
  the screen.

I'm not sure you can do it all, but I'd like to check these things to implement this in a modal that runs from the preferences interface, which is used to install some stuff, so I would like the user not to "lose" the Preferences window, as I have noticed that modals tend to close this window.

Comment: IMHO best practice is to provide settings in the add-on preferences which should be changed *rarely*, ideally one time (when installing the add-on). If there is a setting that the user needs to change quite often they should be part of the regular UI. Also, what you're trying to do here is not really supported and would be *hackish* anyway (...and I personally don't think that's worth it).

Comment: Hi @brockmann I think you are right, but I am really interested in this and to understand if it is feasible with some "Tricks"

Comment: Recommend split up the question, makes it useful to future visitors searching for a solution to eg. resize a window *or* whether the window is minimized. This question might gets closed anyway since opinion based questions are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, But, sorry, i don't understand where an opinion-based question might be. (Just to understand where I'm wrong)

Comment: No problem and you are not "wrong". You just asking for "good practice", "questions and doubts" which is subjective and most likely gets answered with opinions rather than facts and citations (hence off-topic), see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Also one question per post is how this site works.

Comment: I fear the API won't be of much help here and it may be OS-dependent (also it's threading on hostile UX as explained by brockmann) but if you are on windows you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335721/how-can-i-get-the-window-focused-on-windows-and-re-size-it or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python